# Planner error when calling toDatastream after applying Table Aggregation UDF in Table API

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

The Table stream is not able to convert to a Datastream, only after calling a User-defined `TableAggregateFunction`.
Using the [provided gradle project](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.17/docs/dev/configuration/overview/#getting-started) configuration from Flink and adding the Table API dependencies, and then using the [example for user-defined Table Aggregation](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.17/docs/dev/table/functions/udfs/#aggregate-functions) function provided by Flink, I am unable to then call `toDataStream`.

I [created an example repository](https://github.com/tbone69420/aggregation_ts/tree/main) with this set up to be able to reproduce the error.

I [found this bug which was closed](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-15333) without a resolution, but I am not sure it is related. The error output matches what I get.

I also tried to do a print table, but this results in the same error, again only after I run the UDF. This suggests there may be something wrong with the way the aggregation is called or calculated, but unfortunately I have found no examples of the Table Aggregation being implemented aside from the Flink documentation.

`printSchema()`
shows the correct output, but this is based on the signature of the `TableAggregateFunction` and not on the actual execution.